# How can I synchronize my Funambol with Thunderbird / Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, sync

Under Windows a simple Addon exists with wich I can sync my funambol events and contacts with Thunderbird and Lightning. I couldn't find such a tool for Ubuntu yet but it would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are only "inofficial" builds of the Funambol add-on for thunderbird. Take a look at [memotoo.com's site](http://www.memotoo.com/?lang=en), there are build for Windows, Linux 32/64 bit and even OS/X. The site is in german, but you can set the language to english using the controls at the very top of the page.

- At the first page, look for the buttons to select your application (you may have to scroll until you get the thunderbird icon):

  [image: select application to synchronize]
- Click on thunderbird icon to get the download links displayed:

  [image: download links]
- Now, just download the add-on that matches your thunderbird and ubuntu version (32/64 bit). There's even a short documentation how to install the add-on (of course, you'll have to adapt the url to point to your funambol provider).

I'm using those add-ons with lucid, oneiric and with Win7 - works like a charm!

Comment: is there an alternative to funambol these days? They have sadly dropped their support for synching devices...

Comment: @AndreaBorga: personally, i've dropped funambol and moved to a simple, small caldav/carddav server: [baikal](http://sabre.io/baikal/) - i can strongly recommend it! No need for a thunderbird plugin regarding the calendar; only the address book needs an addon to access the carddav data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @tohuwawohu, which add on do you refer to for the phonebook?

Comment: @AndreaBorga: i'm using the SOGo connector: https://sogo.nu/download.html#/frontends (SOGo Homepage -> Download -> Frontends -> Mozilla Thunderbird, Connector, currently version 31.0.5).